# Deep-links work only on GMAIL application

Tags: android, deep-linking

Deep-links are recognized only when opened from Gmail. If I try to open from WhatsApp, Messenger it does not recognize these links. Why?

```
<activity android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName=".main.MainActivity">

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*.www.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/x" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/x" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*.www.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/y" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/y" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**UPDATE:**

I debugged my code and found out, that when I do click a link in gmail, I **do** have a category type ( I later on validate it ), but if I open the link from slack or messenger it's null. What's the reason behind this?

Comment: What links are you referring to?

Comment: for instance `www.com/x` would work perfectly on Gmail, but the same link will not get recognized in WhatsApp or Messenger application.

Comment: I believe that WhatsApp or Messenger only handle regular web links. They let the OS do the heavy lifting of choosing the proper app to open the link.

Comment: @SimonMarquis I updated original question with an update.

Comment: Apps are not required to specify `category` when using Intents (only `action` is required)

Comment: That is bad, isn't it as there is no way to make sure the intent is actually for deep-links. I mean, `ACTION.VIEW` can be defined also from different type of intent (not deep-link).